# Why database creation command fails in SQLCMD in SQL Server docker for linux?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I use `docker-compose.yml` to load my SQL Server image inside a container.
After it's up and running, I create a `command.sh` shell and try to run it to create a database.

```
# command.sh
echo 'creating database from ->' $ModuleName
export query="'create database $ModuleName'"
echo $query
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P my_strong_password -Q $query
```

And it gives me this error:

> Sqlcmd: 'database': Unknown Option. Enter '-?' for help.

Please note that I can't use `-i` switch to use an input `.sql` file, because I'm creating my queries programmatically in shell based on environment variables.

Comment: Does output of `sqlcmd -?` (on linux) state that you should use double quotes? If so, try to replace the single quotes (`'`) for escaped double quotes (`\"`).   `query="\"create database $ModuleName\""`

Comment: second option could be to create a temporary sql-file (i.e. `/tmp/piepeloi.sql`) with the commands in it that you need to run.

Comment: @Luuk, both of your comments helped me. Can you post them as answer so that I can accept them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `sqlcmd -?` shows how to use then `-Q` option. On windows this says `[-Q "cmdline query" and exit]`.

But Windows and Linux differ (or are not consistent) in the use of single- or double quotes.

First option is to try: `sqlcmd -Q "\"create database $ModuleName\""`

Second option is:

- Create a temporary file (i.e. `/tmp/tmp.sql`), and put the SQL statement in that script.
- Use `-i /tmp/tmp.sql` to execute that script.